# Backup VM instances using Azure Backup Services

Tags: azure, backup, azure-virtual-machine

Can I backup VM instances using **Azure Backup Services**, with Site Recovery Vault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Azure Backup doesn't support backup VM instance yet.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to protect ARM VMs with Azure Backup is now in public preview. You can find more information at  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-first-look-arm/

You can also find the steps to protect classic VMs at the same link, although we've had that support for a while.